# Optimizing a function of a matrix

Tags: matrices, optimization, solution-verification, matrix-equations, semidefinite-programming

Let
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
W= & \underset{X}{\mathrm{maximize}}
& &  \log \left|X + K_1\right|- \alpha \log \left|X + K_2\right|\\
& \mathrm{subject \; to}
& & 0 \preceq X \preceq P,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

in which $X$ and $P$ are symmetric positive semi-definite matrices, and $K_1$, and $K_2$ are symmetric *positive definite* matrices, $\alpha>1$ is a scalar, and $|\cdot|$ represents the determinant.

I want to know if the following answer is correct or not

\begin{align}
X^* =\begin{cases}
     P, &\mathrm{if} \quad  \alpha (P+K_1)  \preceq P+K_2 \\
     0, &\mathrm{if} \quad  \alpha K_{1}  \succeq K_{2}\\
         \frac{K_{2}- \alpha K_{1}}{\alpha -1}, &\mathrm{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
   \end{align}

**Remark:** I have solved the above problem by analogy  from

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x}{\mathrm{maximize}}
& &  \log \left(x + k_1\right)- \alpha \log \left(x + k_2\right)\\
& \mathrm{subject \; to}
& & 0 \le x \le  p,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
in which $x\ge 0$, $p\ge0$, $k_1>0$, $k_2>0$, $\alpha>1$ all are scalars.

Comment: I take it your partial ordering is given by "$M \geq N$ if $M − N \geq 0$; i.e., $M − N$ is positive semi-definite".

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct.

Comment: @muaddib: yes, I mean so.

Answer (score 0):

Bob, it's more complicated. The domain $D$ is defined by $0\leq X\leq P$. If $X$ is in the interior of $D$, then an extremum is reached in $X_0=(K_2-\alpha K_1)/(\alpha-1)$ -if $X_0\in int(D)$- (you must prove it). It remains to consider the edge $K$ of $D$; unfortunately $K$ strictly contains $\{0,P\}$; for instance , if $X\in D$ is not invertible or if $X\in D$ and $P-X$ non-invertible , then $X\in K$.